# How validate number fields with validateRegex in a JSF-Page?

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

In a managed bean I have a property of the type int.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Nacharbeit implements Serializable {

private int number;
```

In the JSF page I try to validate this property for 6 digits numeric input only

```
               <h:inputText id="number"
                         label="Auftragsnummer"
                         value="#{myController.nacharbeit.number}"
                         required="true">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="(^[1-9]{6}$)" />
            </h:inputText>
```

On runtime I get an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Is the regex wrong? Or are the ValidateRegex only for Strings?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`<f:validateRegex>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateRegex.html) is intented to be used on `String` properties only. But you've there an `int` property for which JSF would already convert the submitted `String` value to `Integer` before validation. This explains the exception you're seeing.

But as you're already using an `int` property, you would already get a conversion error when you enter non-digits. The conversion error message is by the way configureable by `converterMessage` attribute. So you don't need to use regex at all.

As to the concrete functional requirement, you seem to want to validate the min/max length. For that you should be using [`<f:validateLength>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateLength.html) instead. Use this in combination with the `maxlength` attribute so that the enduser won't be able to enter more than 6 characters anyway.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.number}" maxlength="6">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="6" />
</h:inputText>
```

You can configure the validation error message by the `validatorMessage` by the way. So, all with all it could look like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.number}" maxlength="6"
    converterMessage="Please enter digits only."
    validatorMessage="Please enter 6 digits.">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="6" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can achieve this without regex also

To validate int values:

```
<h:form id="user-form">  
    <h:outputLabel for="name">Provide Amount to Withdraw  </h:outputLabel><br/>  
    <h:inputText id="age" value="#{user.amount}" validatorMessage="You can Withdraw only between $100 and $5000">  
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="100" maximum="5000" />  
    </h:inputText><br/>  
    <h:commandButton value="OK" action="response.xhtml"></h:commandButton>  
</h:form>
```

To validate float values:

```
<h:form id="user-form">  
    <h:outputLabel for="amount">Enter Amount </h:outputLabel>  
    <h:inputText id="name-id" value="#{user.amount}" validatorMessage="Please enter amount between 1000.50 and 5000.99">  
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1000.50" maximum="5000.99"/>  
    </h:inputText><br/><br/>  
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="response.xhtml"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

We needed to validate number fields with validateRegex

Here's how we did it

```
    public class CustomNumberConverter extends NumberConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value) || StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
            return null;
        }

        //needed to raise an error when the number comes with trailing letters 
        if (!value.matches("^[\\d,\\.\\s]+$")) {
            throw new ConverterException("");
        }
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

Then register the custom converter, don't forget to add the parameters supported by the base converter

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>project.converter.customnumberconverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.web.project.converters.CustomNumberConverter</converter-class>
    <property>
        <property-name>pattern</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
        <property-name>maxIntegerDigits</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.Integer</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
        <property-name>minFractionDigits</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.Integer</property-class>
    </property>
</converter>

<tag>
    <tag-name>customConvertNumber</tag-name>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>project.converter.customnumberconverter</converter-id>
    </converter>
</tag>
```

Finally in the view use the custom converter

```
<p:inputText
    value="#{controller.inputValue}"
    maxlength="35"
>
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="9999999999" />
    <s:customConvertNumber pattern="0.00" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
</p:inputText>
```

inputValue used in the controller is a String, in order to overcome the COERCE_ZERO issue (primefaces version 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PrimeFaces, I suggest to simply use the [`p:inputNumber`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml) component. This allows you to set `minValue` and `maxValue`. Way more convenient.

See the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/inputnumber) for more details.