# validatorMessage not used when non-number input is entered

Tags: validation, jsf

I'd like to show a custom message when the user enters a non-number.

For that, I specified `validatorMessage` attribute:

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{bean.commission}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please enter a value"
    validatorMessage="Please enter a number" />
```

The required message appears correctly on empty input, but the validator message doesn't appear on non-number input. Instead, it shows the default message that the input value is not a number.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: And you're positive it's a validation error? What exactly is the message?

Comment: @atbegin-but , how cone you getting validation error if there no validator  in your code ? show your complete (relevant) code , can it be that the validator message you seeing belongs to another field ?

Comment: I have only those lines for this `h:inputText`

Comment: you have no idea,      :(

Comment: @atbegin-but the point he's making is that there is nothing in your code that actually stipulates a validation condition (no `validator`), so it's unlikely you're experiencing a validation error. Try setting the `converterMessage` on that input text instead

Comment: This is a conversion error, not a validation error.

Comment: thank you, it works,  that's all that I needed

Answer (score 1):

You faced a conversion error, not a validation error.

Use `converterMessage` instead.

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{bean.commission}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please enter a value"
    converterMessage="Please enter a number" />
```

The `validatorMessage` is only used on validators specified via `validator` attribute and those via nested `<f:validator>` and `<f:validateXxx>` tags.

The `converterMessage` is used on converters specified via `converter` attribute and those via nested `<f:converter>` and `<f:convertXxx>` tags, **and** also on auto-registered converters for a specific class, such as [`IntegerConverter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/integerconverter) in case of `int`/`Integer` typed `value`.

#### See also:

- [Accept only digits for h:inputText value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269507/accept-only-digits-for-hinputtext-value/)
- [How validate number fields with validateRegex in a JSF-Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501845/how-validate-number-fields-with-validateregex-in-a-jsf-page/)