# Accept only digits for h:inputText value

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, input, decimal

Is there a way to confirm the value of an `h:inputText` in JSF, which should accepts only digits. Means it can be an `Integer` or the `float`.

If I type  `12s3a562.675`  ,  `a5678s12`  ,  `68712haf.563345`  or any other such kind of values, then it should show an error. Otherwise it accepts and proceeds.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just bind the input value to a `Double`, or better, `BigDecimal` property instead of `String`.

```
private BigDecimal number; // Double can also, but beware floating-point-gui.de
```

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.number}" />
```

JSF has [builtin converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/package-summary.html) for those types which will kick in automatically. You can customize the converter message as below:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.number}" converterMessage="Please enter digits only." />
```

Answer (score 25):

`<h:inputText onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"/>` is a short way if you want to accept integers only.

It has the advantage over `type="number"` that you can't even enter a non-digit

Comment: dasLort: plus one from my side. What should I do so as to allow only digits and enter key

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari something like this: `onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;else if(event.which === 13) myFunction()"` but I still prefer to put all on a separated function

Comment: Would disabling JavaScript not bypass this validation?

Comment: @ChristopheWeis it would, however as BalusC said [q] JSF has builtin converters for those types which will kick in automatically.  [/q]

Answer (score 13):

If you add this to your xhtml

> xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"

and use the inputext for  numbers of Primefaces Extensions called **pe:inputNumber**  , which not only validate your numbers but decimals also, may be more complete.

```
<pe:inputNumber value="#{beanTest.myValue}" thousandSeparator="" decimalSeparator="." decimalPlaces="0" />
```

Comment: I tried to add the extension library to my project and use InputNumber but it was not configuring properly. so would you please share how to configure to use extension component along with primefaces components. I'm currently using primefaces 5.2 in my project.

Comment: This is now part of PrimeFaces. See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to use Primefaces, You can attach a `<p:keyFilter>` to either a `<h:inputText>` or `<p:inputText>`.

Example:

```
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{bean.intValue}" />
<p:keyFilter for="text1" mask="pint" />

<p:inputText id="text2" value="#{bean.numberValue}" >
  <p:keyFilter mask="num" />
</p:inputText>
```

This will block keyboard input to allow *only* valid integer (`int`/`pint`) or decimal (`num`/`pnum`) input. The `pnum` and `pint` types only allows positive input (no sign).

Comment: ...but prevent paste key : ctrl+v

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
<h:inputText value="SomeValue" converter="javax.faces.Double" />
```

Comment: this one is wrong because ".123" pass the validation(with the dot at the beginning). I think you should use '<pe:inputNumber value="#{beanTest.myValue}"  thousandSeparator="" decimalSeparator="." decimalPlaces="0" /> '

Comment: @dmatos `double a = .123;` is 100% valid in Java (for test it copy this line in Java code). **javax.faces.Double** is standard JSF converter which cover Java **double**.

Answer (score 6):

This is working for me

```
onkeypress="if( (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) ) return false;"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some different options:

- You can use `@Digits` from [bean validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html).
- You can use [f:convertNumber](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html).
- You can validate the input in a backing bean method (you'll easily find tutorials for this)
- If jsf 2.2 and html5 is an option for you, you can use `<input type="number" />`
- Or you can use your own Javascript validation.

I think that the best options are either using **Bean validation**, **f:convertNumber** or going with **HTML5** as these are the cleanest and give you the least redundant code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
but because I have almost 30-40 input fields, so bean validation won't be a good method.  

     And then I have tried f:convertNumber with pattern/type/digitsOnly, but its not throwing the error.
So, do you suggest any other easy method to check it out.

Comment: f:convertNumber will accept input that starts with digits and try to make a guess what number it should be so 12f will become 12. It won't accept input that starts with non-digit chars. Why would bean validation not work? You would only need to put one annotation for each field in the backing bean corresponding to one of your inputs. Even a bit less code than f:convertNumber. Also `@Digits` requires the input to be only numerical.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JS validation

First, you need to define a JS function to validate the input

```
function validateInput(regexString) {
    var theEvent = window.event || event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    if (key >= 46) {
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var regex = new RegExp("^" + regexString + "$");
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
                theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, in your h:input, capture the onKeyPress event and call the function

```
<h:inputText value="..." onKeyPress="validateInput('[0-9]*')/>
```

And it will only let you enter numbers.

You can easily extend this use to other case when you need to validate whit other regex.

Note, this only work with key press, if you want to capture other user event, use the proper tag.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But as I have written that I have 30-40 inputs with values till 12 digits(6.6), so calling the javascript code for a thousand times by using keypress won't be good Idea.
Do yu suggest any other method.

Comment: @abhi this JS reacts on user input, it's imposible for the user to enter a thousand numbers simultaneously. Please, explain better your problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for integer values, you could use JSF 2.2 [passthrough attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#sthref393) to use [input `type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) like this:

```
<html xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:inputText a:type="number" value="#{bean.integer}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PrimeFaces Extension for  you can use  now!

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<h:inputText>
   <f:validateRegex pattern="\d*(.\d+)?"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Can't make it work with JSF 1. <f:validateRegex> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: validateRegex

Comment: I have a float variable and JSF throws this error: java.lang.ClassCastException - java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String