# JSF <h:inputText> should accept just number

Tags: jsf, valueconverter

i 've been looking a lot about how to make my  allows just number to be inserted inside , seems quite easy but it doesn't work in anyway.

I have this code :

```
<p:fragment id="thresoldPrice">
    <h:inputText type="number"value="" disabled="#{!tradingFunnelCBean.tradingFunnelMBean.conditionalOrder}" styleClass="#{!tradingFunnelCBean.tradingFunnelMBean.conditionalOrder ? '' : 'num-col'} middle-space">                                                     
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#.####" integerOnly="true" maxFractionsDigit="4"/>
        <p:watermark for="thresoldPrice"value="#{localizationBean.getMessageValue('EP3.GIMB.TRADINGFUNNEL.PRIVATE.LABEL.WATERMARK', languagePreferenceBean.selectedPreference)}" />                     
    </h:inputText>
</p:fragment>
```

but it keeps accepting String values. i would also like to make the value inserted in this format "#.####" but the pattern attribute of the h:inputText doesn't make anything.

Any suggestion?

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269507/accept-only-digits-for-hinputtext-value

Comment: <h:inputText type="number" value="">           <f:convertNumber pattern="#.####" integerOnly="true"maxFractionsDigit="4"/>      </h:inputText>

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: i can't use javascript

Comment: <h:inputText type="number" value="">                                         <f:convertNumber pattern="#.####" integerOnly="true"maxFractionsDigit="4"/>                              </h:inputText>

Comment: Your value implies a string. Remove `value=""` or use `value="#{bean.number}"` on a real `Integer` property and retry.

Comment: You should bind the value attribute to an Integer property in your bean.