# How to Validate number field from <f:validateRegex>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to validate input value from the below code where i am using regex validation

```
<h:inputText id="min" maxlength="5" value="#{bean.intValue}"
    validatorMessage="Please enter valid Integer value">
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[1-9]\d*$"/>
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
</h:inputText>
```

Note-> `intValue` type is `Integer`

But i am getting below class cast exception so below message is saying we cannot use `<f:validateRegex />` with a `Integer` value if Yes Why ?

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String  at
>   javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.validate(RegexValidator.java:160)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.richfaces.context.PartialViewExecuteVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewExecuteVisitCallback.java:55)
>   [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.context.BaseExtendedVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(BaseExtendedVisitContext.java:321)
>   [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.richfaces.component.AbstractTab.visitTree(AbstractTab.java:317)
>   [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.visitTree(AbstractTogglePanel.java:924)
>   [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.richfaces.component.AbstractTab.visitTree(AbstractTab.java:317)
>   [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.visitTree(AbstractTogglePanel.java:924)
>   [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.executeComponents(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:278)
>   [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartialExecutePhase(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:258)
>   [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:215)
>   [richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1162)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]    at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.edgefilter.EdgeFilter.doFilter(EdgeFilter.java:29)
>   [classes:]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

**EDIT-**

As **@BalusC** already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501845/how-validate-number-fields-with-validateregex-in-a-jsf-page) but i want use not able to enter any decimal value as well also use should not enter value like `01` or `0089`

Comment: Hi @balusC how to ignore float value or `01` or `0078` kind of value with your solution

Comment: That's a new question. Just ask a new question. E.g. "How to validate that a number field does not start with 0"